# Rails Store array parameter in different row with join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, mysql-workbench

In rails 4 application With `has_many :through` relations

**city.rb**

```
has_many :business_type_cities
has_many :business_types, :through => :business_type_cities
```

**business_type.rb**

```
has_many :business_type_cities 
has_many :cities, :through => :business_type_cities
```

**businesstypecity.rb**

```
belongs_to :buness_types
belongs_to :cities
```

**business_types_controller.rb**

```
def create
  if business_type.save
    BusinessTypeCity.create :business_type_id => business_type.id,        :city_id => params[:cities]
    flash[:notice] = 'Business Type Created Successfully!'
    redirect_to admin_business_types_path
  else
    flash[:error] = business_type.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
  end
end
```

but here `city_id` is `array` and I want to store `business_type_id` and `city_id` in one row, other `city_id` will store in different row with same `business_type_id`.

Response I get is following:

```
"business_type"=>{"name"=>"test", "review_type"=>"review_with_rating"}, "cities"=>["293", "1091", "1200"], "commit"=>"Create Business Type"
```

Thanks

Comment: Simple, I need to iterate params[:cities] with each do. Although if you have a better answer then interested in that. Thanks any way for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be what you suggested in the comment. Here's what I usually do

```
existing_city_ids = business_type.city_ids
business_type.city_ids = existing_city_ids | params[:cities].map(&:to_i)
```

First getting all the existing city ids for the current business type. Then combine with the new ones, using `||` to avoid duplicates, and mapping `params[:cities]` to int to match with `business_type.city_ids (returns an array of int)`